# Is there rational number x,y satisfy this equation?

Tags: number-theory

Is there rational number x,y satisfy the equation :
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+4}-x}{2}=\tanh(y)$$

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $y=0$ there are no solutions for *x*. For rational $y\neq0$, the left side is algebraic, whereas the right side is transcendental. So there are no possible rational solutions.